# How to add title to a networkD3 visualisation when saving as a web page?

Tags: r, htmlwidgets, networkd3, htmltools

I have created a interactive visualisation using the following code:

```
library(networkD3)

nodes = data.frame("name" = c("node1", "node2","node3", "node4", "node5", "node6", "node7"))
links = as.data.frame(matrix(c(
0,1,7937,
0,2,6990,
0,3,2483,
1,4,2120,
2,4,666,
3,4,282,
1,5,4583,
2,5,5657,
3,5,731,
1,6,1234,
2,6,756,
3,6,1470), byrow = TRUE, ncol = 3))

names(links) = c("source", "target", "value")

sankey <- sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes,
          Source = "source", Target = "target",
          Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
          fontSize= 12, nodeWidth = 15)'
```

This is my first time using the networkD3 package (or any interactive package for that matter) and from playing around I found that to keep it interactive it has to be published as a webpage (or is there another way??) but looking through the documentation for the package I can't see a way to add a title or a caption / comments. I want to share this piece of work round so need to explain what each level means on the published webpage ideally

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no feature built-in to `networkD3` to add titles or captions, but you can use functions in the `htmlwidgets` package to prepend or append content to an `htmlwidget`. There are numerous options, but for example....

```
library(htmlwidgets)
library(htmltools)

sankey <- htmlwidgets::prependContent(sankey, htmltools::tags$h1("Title"))
sankey <- htmlwidgets::appendContent(sankey, htmltools::tags$p("Caption"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can I ask why you call it like htmlwidgets::prepend...      instead of how you normally call a function?

Comment: just to be clear where the function is coming from... it's technically unnecessary once you've loaded the packages with `library(htmlwidgets)` and `library(htmltools)`

Comment: `%>%`
        `prependContent("Text")` I ended up using this to add a title, but it keeps pushing my viz down and cutting the bottom off. This stays off even when saving as a webpage. Is there anyway I can stop this from happening?

Comment: try `sankey$sizingPolicy$viewer$fill <- FALSE`

Answer (score 5):

Responding to the comment, "I ended up using this to add a title, but it keeps pushing my viz down and cutting the bottom off. This stays off even when saving as a webpage. Is there anyway I can stop this from happening?"

I tried the suggested reply of adding sankey$sizingPolicy$viewer$fill <- FALSE, however, it made my sankey smaller than I wanted it.  I found out that you can adjust the width and height of the Sankey prior to adding the HTML widget by adding width=(desired width) and height=(desired height) and this creates the space to then add in the title and the comment, as suggested by CJ Yetman.

```
library(networkD3)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(htmltools)

nodes = data.frame("name" = c("node1", "node2","node3", "node4", "node5", "node6", "node7"))
links = as.data.frame(matrix(c(
  0,1,7937,
  0,2,6990,
  0,3,2483,
  1,4,2120,
  2,4,666,
  3,4,282,
  1,5,4583,
  2,5,5657,
  3,5,731,
  1,6,1234,
  2,6,756,
  3,6,1470), byrow = TRUE, ncol = 3))

names(links) = c("source", "target", "value")

sankey <- sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes,
                        Source = "source", Target = "target",
                        Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
                        fontSize= 12, nodeWidth = 15,
                        width= 900, height=600)


sankey <- htmlwidgets::prependContent(sankey, htmltools::tags$h1("Title"))
sankey <- htmlwidgets::appendContent(sankey, htmltools::tags$p("Caption"))

sankey
```